# Obtener campos especificos en una tabla html con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-tabla

Hola estoy intentando obtener 2 campos especificos de una tabla *HTML* con *Javascript* y guardarlos en un arreglo.. luego estos arreglos guardarlo en otro arreglo que los contiene todos...los campos serian de las columas **Capitulo** y **%** ej: `arreglo = [[11100, 0.0], [11102, 7.00], [11160, 1.00]...]` esta es la tabla... Gracias de antemano.

```html
<table border="1" id="tabla">
  <tbody>
    <tr id="encabezado">
      <th>Año</th>
      <th>Capitulo</th>
      <th>Importe</th>
      <th>%</th>
      <th>% iva</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018</td>
      <td class="capitulo">11100</td>
      <td>305000</td>
      <td class="porciento">0.00</td>
      <td>0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018</td>
      <td class="capitulo">11160</td>
      <td>54545</td>
      <td class="porciento">1.00</td>
      <td>22.00</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yo uso esto: `var selData = table.rows(".selected").data().toArray();` pero con jquery y datatables, tal vez te sirva, tambien puedes capturar el click con: `$('#tablaDatos').on('click', 'tr', function () { //tu codigo });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con unas pocas líneas de Javascript podría ser así:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Año</th>
                    <th>Capítulo</th>
                    <th>Importe</th>
                    <th>%</th>
                    <th>% IVA</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table-data">
                <tr>
                    <td>Año 1</td>
                    <td>Capítulo 1</td>
                    <td>Importe 1</td>
                    <td>1%</td>
                    <td>IVA 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Año 2</td>
                    <td>Capítulo 2</td>
                    <td>Importe 2</td>
                    <td>2%</td>
                    <td>IVA 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Año 3</td>
                    <td>Capítulo 3</td>
                    <td>Importe 3</td>
                    <td>3%</td>
                    <td>IVA 3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script>
            // Definimos el array donde guardaremos los datos...
            var data = [];

            // Obtenemos la variable con las filas de tbody...
            var rows = document.getElementById('table-data').rows;

            // Recorremos las filas y añadimos al array el valor de las celdas con los offset 1 (capítulo) y 3 (porcentaje)...
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                data.push([ rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML, rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML ]);
            }

            // Ya tenemos los datos guardados, ahora hacemos lo que queramos con ellos...
            console.log(data);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias! @o1dskoo1 exactamente era eso exelente respuesta...

Answer (score 2):

Esto hace lo mismo

```
let data = [].map.call(document.getElementById('table-data').rows, 
           tr => [tr.cells[1].textContent, tr.cells[3].textContent]);

console.log(data);
```